# Why does my banner create a horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: html

• When I insert the banner for the site a horizontal scroll bar is created, how can I solve this? That the image resolution is good.
The same thing happens to me at the table, he creates a vertical scroll bar. How can I solve these things? I don't know how to use @media to optimize all resolutions. Do you think I can solve this somehow?

**Link preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2e9Y.jpg
Banner: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLT83.jpg**

```css
.banner{
position: relative;
top: 0;
margin-top: 4.3%;
right: -80px;
}
```

```html
    <body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
  <img class="banner" src="img\banner.png" alt="Banner">
</div>
```

Comment: There should be overflow happens. Do you need `right: -80px;` in the `.banner`?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to hide scrollbars without regard to whether the whole banner is displayed, then you can use overflow:

```
.banner{
overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
position: relative;
top: 0;
margin-top: 4.3%;
right: -80px;
}
```

Comment: What did you see? And did you try the suggestion from yinsweet above? Why do you need right: -80px; ?       

Simply saying 'this does not work' is not very helpful.